# Get folder path in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, directory

**Task:** Copy Folder and contents from one vdi to another vdi. This application is internally facing within the company.

**Method:**

1. In jsp have user browse for folder
2. The folder selection is in a text box, the folder path is passed into an action class
3. The folder path is placed into a teradata table
4. A script is called to query the table for the source path and target path (pre-determined) and make the copy

**Due Dilligence:** So far I have tried the `<input type="file"`, which selects a file, not a folder. Also, the file path is not passed through due to security reasons. I have read other possible solutions but none work.

**Question:** Are sevlets a viable solution, and if so, how do I create one?

Comment: You do realize that an <input file=""/> will let the user browse her local filesystem, not the servers, right?

Comment: yes I do.  The vdi is mapped as a network drive onto the computer, so in a sense it is on the local file system

Comment: But it would have to be mapped to the same network drive for every user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to go with no. There are several reasons for this.

- A Java Enterprise Edition application (be it a Servlet or Java Server Page) is not supposed to access the file system directly.
- It is inherently unsafe to expose internal infrastructure through an external website.

I think you need to break it up a bit more.

1. Save a list of shares the server has access to in a data store of some sort, like a new teradata table or  for a quick proof of concept plain text file (if you're on Linux you can use the output of something like `showmount -e localhost`).
2. Let the user pick the src share from a combobox or something similar.
3. Continue from your step 2.

This gives you two immediately obviously advantages, which may or may not be relevant.

- You can use the system without having access to the physical shares.
- You can add metadata (like description or aliases).